# Can I keep my Intents and entities on-premises?

Tags: dialogflow-es

For security reasons, I don't want to save the Intents and Entities in the dialogflow cloud, instead I want to keep those on-premises. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. You're developing an agent at Google's end. To make use of their platform & NLP, you will have to create intents there only (which will auto-store everything on at their end). Instead, you can take backup of your content or if security is the only concern, you can share bot to specific people only by adding their email-ids & giving them access as developer or reviewer.

[image]